# How to create a custom Ubuntu disc?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I would like to have a CD with a custom Linux installation, for example, when installed have Ubuntu (could be another distro, but preferably) with Eclipse, Aptana, MySql, Postegresql, PHP, Django, Opera, Chromium, and my_image.jpg as background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) is what you are looking for? It seems to be exactly what you need - a step-by-step guide to creating your own customised ubuntu installation CD.

Answer (score 1):

The Fedora Project has [an app called Revisor](http://revisor.fedoraunity.org/) that does what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i dont in ubuntu but in fedora u can install

### yum install revisor

then u make u r choice of cd /dvd

Comment: if did some diff step pls share with us

Answer (score 0):

I have used Remastersys in the past. Take a look:

http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/index.html